# How to replace triangular quotes in Python?

Tags: python

I want to remove triangular quotes and their contents. Here is an example string:

Example **^x^** string

I need: Example string

Comment: you can use the .replace() method.

Comment: check out `re.sub()`

Comment: @Sam how does the .replace() method affect the __contents__ of the quotes?

Comment: I suggest you provide example input *and* output, without `*`s mixed in.

Comment: Try: `"".join(string_name.split("^")[::2])`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) to search for a regex patter and substitute it:

```py
import re

s = "test^1^123"
result = re.sub("\^.*\^", "", s)
print(result)  # test123
```

The first argument to `re.sub` is the pattern (in this case a literal `^` followed by any number of any other characters and another literal `^`) and the second is the string to replace the pattern with (in this case an empty string)

If multiple triangle quoted strings are possible in the same imput then the regex should be [*non-greedy*](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#greedy-versus-non-greedy):

```py
import re

s = "test^1^123"
result = re.sub("\^.*?\^", "", s)
print(result)  # test123
```

Comment: Try that with the string `"^x^middle^y^"`

Comment: @khelwood Yep that's an edge case that is not well defined by the question... if the shortest string is needed then the regex would be `\^.*?\^`. I updated my answer